# Как происходит интеграция из ERP в аналитическую систему?

Tags: sql-server, интеграция, erp

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, источники, в которых я смогу подробно разобраться в механике процессов интеграции данных.

Вводные:

- есть ERP
- Есть аналитическая система

Как и с помощью каких средств производится интеграция данных?
Например, каждую ночь из ERP поступают данные о продажах и остатков товаров за прошедший день.
В эту же ночь обратно в ERP отправляются аналитические данные.

Я знаю что используют T-SQL.
Знаю что из ERP файлы кладут на SFTP.
Далее используются ридеры, написанные на Java.

Мне нужен источник для понимания полного процесса и вариантов построения интеграций.

Comment: Pentaho Data Integration

Comment: ETL, SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)